# Github pages are not refreshing. How to turn off or at least invalidate server side caching?

Tags: http, caching, github-pages

**Context**

My github pages are not refreshing. After diagnosing my conclusion is it's a server side caching effect.

**What I did + diagnostic results**

- The site is working OK.
- I made a change in index.html in my local
  repo, then **commit** and push
- I completely cleared my browser cache (btw also using cache clear plugins, and Chrome dev tools set not using cache)
- Reloaded the page, with ctrl+f5 and ctrl+R (change is **not** applied)
- Checked using github.com read index.html, the change is there, committed.
- Monitored the traffic with Fiddler. The request for index.html sent, full response received, the content is the old NOT changed.
- Examined the response header with Fiddler, says: (see header exhibit)

**Reverse diagnostic**

- I've issued a request with a usual trick typeing: index.html?v001orAnythingYouWant and **I got the new version of the page**

**Problem**

Problem solved one can say, but it is not true. When I refresh images, css, js still this effect will prevent me to see the new result.

**Question**

How can I configure or overcome this server side caching, of course only for development/testing time?

**Response header exhibit**

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: GitHub.com
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Last-Modified: Fri, 06 May 2016 12:24:29 GMT
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Expires: Fri, 06 May 2016 12:45:44 GMT
Cache-Control: max-age=600
X-GitHub-Request-Id: B91F111E:5AA6:47804:572C8F9F
Content-Length: 43752
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Date: Fri, 06 May 2016 12:35:57 GMT
Via: 1.1 varnish
Age: 13
Connection: keep-alive
X-Served-By: cache-fra1238-FRA
X-Cache: HIT
X-Cache-Hits: 1
Vary: Accept-Encoding
X-Fastly-Request-ID: 1758f53052edbfb40a0044407d53d5654ad1e983
```

Comment: I've tried to reproduce on a fresh repo. No cache invalidation problem. You'd better try to reach Github directly.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. My repo also a fresh one, created today. It is a project pages, not a user pages, if that make a difference. Otherwise I do not think it is a unique isolated case. I did no special settings, all are defaults. See the header: the response coming from a server cache.

Comment: What's your github name ? I will add you as a collaborator on my test repo.